# Encoding protocol's computed property

Tags: ios, swift, protocols, codable

I have some properties which I want to encode in my every response model. I want to create a solution which I can use for both classes and structs. For this, I created a protocol with all my shared properties in it (as computed properties). I want them to be encoded with the class/struct to be extended with that protocol.

Here is my protocol

```
protocol BaseMainRequestable: Codable { }

extension BaseMainRequestable {

   var encryptionkey: String? {
       get {
           return BaseMainRequestHandler.shared.baseMainRequestConfigs?.encryptionkey
       }
       set {
           BaseMainRequestHandler.shared.baseMainRequestConfigs?.encryptionkey = newValue
       }
  }

}
```

Here is my class

```
class TestModel: BaseMainRequestable {

   var testProperty: String?

   init(testProperty: String) {
       self.testProperty = testProperty
   }

   required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
       fatalError("init(from:) has not been implemented")
   }

   enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
       case testProperty
   }

   func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
       var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
       try container.encodeIfPresent(testProperty, forKey: .testProperty)
   }

}
```

I tried without implementing encode method too but didn't work.

Comment: Shouldn’t encryptionkey be part of the protocol?

Comment: Already tried that as well but didn’t work